# Graph Theory : Perfect Matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

**The problem is:**
Children begin to awaken preferences for certain toys and activities at an early age. Due to the reduced number of different toys, a nursery is looking for a way to meet the tastes of children in the best possible way during children's entertainment hours. Therefore, given the list of toys that each child in the school likes, you should find, using graphs, the maximum number of children that can play, at the same time, with any toy of interest.

Entry The first line of the entry contains three integers N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), M (1 ≤ M ≤ 100) and L (0 ≤ L ≤ 10,000), representing the number of children in the nursery, the number of toys and the total number of indications of toys of interest to students, respectively. Each child is uniquely identified by an integer from 0 to N-1 and each toy is uniquely identified by an integer from 0 to M-1. Each of the next L lines contains two integers c and b, indicating that a child c likes to play with toy b. Output Your program should print a line containing the maximum number of children who can play simultaneously with any toy of your taste

```
INPUT EXAMPLE: 
 3 4 6
 0 0
 0 2
 0 3
 1 1
 2 1
 2 3

 Output
 3
```

My solution:

```
class Graph: 
def __init__(self,_childs,_toys):
    toys = _toys*[0]
    self.graph = _childs*[toys]
    self.childs = _childs
    self.toys = _toys

def add_match(self,child,toy):
    self.graph[child][toy] = 1

def perfect_match(self, l, myToys, match): 
    for r in range(self.toys): 
      if self.graph[l][r] and match[r] == False: 
        match[r] = True
        if myToys[r] == -1 or self.perfect_match(myToys[r],myToys, match): 
          myToys[r] = l
          return True
    return False

def max_match(self):
    myToys = [-1] * self.toys
    result = 0
    for i_child in range(self.childs):
      match = [False] * self.toys
      if self.perfect_match(i_child, myToys, match):
        result += 1
    return result


g1 = Graph(3,4)
g1.add_match( 0 , 0 )
g1.add_match( 0 , 2 )
g1.add_match( 0 , 3 )
g1.add_match( 1 , 1 )
g1.add_match( 2 , 1 )
g1.add_match( 2 , 3 )
print(g1.max_match())
# output = 3

g2 = Graph(5,5)
g2.add_match( 0 , 1 )
g2.add_match( 0 , 2 )
g2.add_match( 1 , 1 )
g2.add_match( 2 , 0 )
g2.add_match( 2 , 3 )
g2.add_match( 3 , 3 )
g2.add_match( 4 , 3 )
print(g2.max_match())
# output = 4
```

But i got fail in some tests: (i dont have acess to test, i just want mean that this solution get a 52% score, so maybe is just resolve some input special cases...)

```
enter code here
Test 6
WRONG
Test 7
WRONG
Test 8
WRONG
Test 9
WRONG

Test 12
WRONG
Test 13
WRONG
Test 14

Test 22
WRONG
Test 23
WRONG
Test 24
WRONG
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question uses a simple observation. If there are two kids, where the first one likes only 2 toys but the 2nd one likes 20 toys, then you'll greedily try to assign a toy to the 1st kid, and then to the 2nd one (since he has more choices).
Use this property along with backtracking to solve the problem.